# Clear checked items from a listbox without firing itemcheck event

Tags: c#, .net, mdi, checkedlistbox

I got a checkedlist box in form2 (clbForm2) where i'm explicity mapping it to an item check event. Now i need to uncheck all the checked items of the control in Form1, from within form2. On unchecking the items, it'z firing the item check event. Is there any way to skip the event. I'd written code within that, which i dont want to run when called from form2. Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unbind the event and rebind it.

```
_checkBox.CheckedChanged -= new System.EventHandler(yourEventHandler);
// Do Check as you want.
_checkBox.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(yourEventHandler);
```

Comment: @If you open the designer class you would be able to find the event binding. Just copy that line and do as I have done in the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use a flag rather than to unbind/rebind...

Create a class level variable such as...

```
private bool processCheckChange = true;
```

Then in you event handler do...

```
OnCheckedChange()
{
   if(processCheckChange)
   {
      //Handle check change
   }
}
```

Then when you want to uncheck all items...

```
UncheckAllItems()
{
   processCheckChange = false;
   //Uncheck all items
   processCheckChange = true;
}
```

I think this should do the job

Comment: If there are many items to be checked, then unbinding would be the best rather than firing events unnecessarily.

Comment: @CharithJ, Yes that is a good point that I had not thought of